# Binary data column not showing correct format/values in R

Tags: r

Im working on a project where I'm using airline data. I have retrieved the datafrom Kaggle, link to the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/teejmahal20/aurline-passenger-satisfaction. I'm interested in the satisfaction variable which is a binary variable. Now my problem is that R is not showing the proper summary of this column. Example:

```
summary (airline $ Satisfaction)
```

Gives the output:

```
Length = 103904
Class: character
Mode: character
```

Now when i use this:

```
str(airline)
```

I get all the data about each column. Here teh satisfaction column gives:

```
(1)
    $ satisfaction :chr "neutral or dissatisfied", "satisfied", "neutral or dissatisfied"...
```

I think the correct format of this column should be:

```
(2)
    $ satisfaction :Factor w/ 2 levels  "neutral or dissatisfied", "satisfied": 2 1 2 2...
```

Now my question is, how do i transform the binary data column from (1) to (2)? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
airline$Satisfaction <- as.factor(airline$Satisfaction)
```

solved it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer of [Larimar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19027605/larimar), you may consider using the argument `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` or similar when importing the dataset for example with `read.csv()`